# How can I run a custom command at build time in meson?

Tags: build, embedded, cross-compiling, meson-build

in my projects I adopt a semantic versioning scheme following the standard described by [semver](https://semver.org/). I obtain something like this: product_v1.2.3-alpha-dirty.elf .

I work with embedded system and with make I usually generate a version_autogen.h file at compile time that contains both information of the version number , e.g 1.4.3.1, and current git repository, e.g --dirty, --clean and so on, using shell commands.

I'm starting to using meson and it is very easy and flexible but the custom commands like

```
run_command('command', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
```

are available only at *configure* time while I need them at *compile* time to retrieve information like git status and similar.

How can I do that?

Comment: Since you're asking about a specific tool ('meson'), the question has nothing to do with C.

Comment: have you looked at [`custom_target()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#custom_target)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a deeper research I found that custom_target() (as suggested by [nielsdg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2921914/nielsdg)) can do my job. I did something like this:

```
# versioning
version_autogen_h = custom_target(
    'version_autogen.h',
    output : 'version_autogen.h',
    input : 'version_creator.sh',
    command : ['@INPUT@', '0', '0', '1', 'alpha.1', '@OUTPUT@' ],
)
```

where `version_creator.sh` is my bash script that retrieves git info and creates the file `version_autogen.h` given the version numbers passed as the command arguments. The custom target is created at compile time, so my script is executed at compile time as well, exactly when I want it to be.

I also discovered that in meson there is the possibility to use *generators* to do something similar to this but in that case they *transform* an input file in one or more output file, so they didn't fit my case where I didn't need to have a file as input but just versioning numbers.

Answer (score 2):

meson has specialized command for this job - [vcs_tag](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#vcs_tag)

> This command detects revision control commit information at build time
> and places it in the specified output file. This file is guaranteed to
> be up to date on every build. Keywords are similar to custom_target.

, so it'd look a bit shorter with possibility to avoid generation script and have just

```
git_version_h = vcs_tag(input : 'version.h.in',
                       output : 'version.h')
```

where *version.h.in* file that you should provide with @VCS_TAG@ string that will be replaced, e.g.

```
#define MYPROJ_VERSION "@VCS_TAG@"
```

of course, you can have file header and naming according to your project style and possibly to add other definitions also. It is also possible to use another replace string and own command line to generate version, e.g.

```
vcs_tag(command: [
        'git', '--git-dir', meson.build_root(),
        'describe', '--tags', '--long',
        '--match', '?.*.*', '--always'
    ],
    ...
    )
```

which I found and adapted from [here](https://code.videolan.org/rist/librist/-/blob/054314d35186611580954ef854ce040087cd11cf/include/meson.build)